# How to disable form submission only while pressing enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, bootstrap-4, enter

I need to prevent only form submit while pressing Enter button. That will not affect other functions because my form contains **bootstrap tag input** , This function will not be work when I disable Enter key using below code
This is the code I have used

```
$(document).keypress(
  function(event){
    if (event.which == '13') {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Try :  `13` not `'13'`.  `event.which` is number not string.

Comment: yes it worked. I need to use this script for a particular form only not for all forms